# Nuxt3 - Netlify: useAsyncData not call when route change

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, netlify

I have an app by Nuxt3, deploy to Netlify. My problem is: the useAsyncData is not called when my route change. I use NuxtLink to navigate between pages as normally.

It WORKS perfectly on localhost. It is just not work when deploy on Netlify.

This is my async data code:

```
const { data } = await useAsyncData(
  'get-blogs',
  async () => {
    try {
      const response = await getBlogs();
      if (response?.success) {
        return response?.data || [];
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return [];
    }
  },
  { lazy: true },
);
```

I also already tried to remove lazy: true, problem still happens.

Can you please give me any advice. Thank you.

Comment: assuming `getBlogs` makes some kind of fetch request, have you checked your browser's network tab in dev tools to confirm it's not sending a request and that the problem is not with the fetch?  Usually production problems with fetch requests are related to CORs, firewalls, proxies, etc... network issues basically, so you'll need confirm the issue is what you say, that the function is not being called at all instead of a problem with the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem come from the key get-blogs. We need to use different key for different page. If use the same key for all page, the useAsyncData will call only once.